# Get results from Google geocoder into an array?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mootools

I have the following code:

```
var data = geocoder.geocode({'address': 'new york'}, function (results, status)
{
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        response($.map(results, function(item) 
        {
            return
            {
                value: item.formatted_address
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

I need to get the output of the data to look like this:

```
var data = [
    {value: 'some1'},
    {value: 'some2'},
    {value: 'some3'}
];
```

I really don't have a clue what Im doing to get it into that state and I'm not sure what exactly is returned by the initial geocoder request. The info on the google code website was rather limited when it came to explaining the above function.

Any idea how I can do it? Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, your return statement is getting auto-semicoloned. So you will always return `undefined`. It basicly means `return; {value: ...};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Geocoder.geocode()` does not return any values, so you CANNOT do:

```
var data = geocoder.geocode({'address': 'new york'}, function (results, status) {
```

Moreover, the callback `function (results, status) {...}` that you specify in the above call is called asynchronously by the geocoder when it finished the geocoding. So, you need to use the results in the callback itself, e.g. filling some textbox etc. Here is a template using pure Javascript, you can adapt it to your JS framework appropriately:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': 'new york'}, 
    function (results, status) {     
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {         
                alert(i + ": " + results[i].formatted_address);
            }             
        }         
    }
);
```

Comment: Cool, but Im still a little clueless of howto form the array that is "Data"

Comment: What is exactly are `value` and `some-i` in your `data`? But again, although you could have any global variable `data` and fill it in the callback as you like, it would not be useful, because you do not know when this variable obtains new values from the geocoder. The only way is to process the `results` in the callback, e.g. by defining and calling another function `process(results) {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

`.map` returns a jQuery object. To get the regular array, use `get`

```
var data = $.map(results, function(item) {
    return { value: item.formatted_address };
    }).get();
```

Comment: Would you mind reposting my original function modified with ur idea? Just to be clear, I'm using Mootools 1.3, NOT jQuery. some of my original code may have been copied from a jQuery function, I just don't know how much.

Comment: mooTools may have different API. I'm not familiar with mooTools but googling tels me that `hash` may be a good starting point: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Hash

Comment: hash is Deprecated in mootools 1.3